# How expand collapse on menu to be implemented?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am new on bigcommerence any one guide me how can i implement + icon functionality on clicking menu item?

here is my website: [forevermodo](http://www.forevermodo.com/)

when i click on "New In" menu button in mobile view it takes me to a link but i want it to expand the sub menu instead.

any one guide me what should i do here? any help would be appreciated.

[image]